# How to plot a line and dots on it using 2 lists in matplotlib?

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

I have 2 lists:

```
losses = [12,13,15,10,9,8]
dots = [1,0,0,1,0,0]
```

How can I plot the main line from the `losses` list, and wherever there's a `1` in the `dots` list have a dot on that line?

I currently have something like this (note that it's 2 different lists from the above example so the values are a bit different)

```
plt.plot(losses, c = 'b')
plt.plot(dots, c='r');
```

But I'm not sure how to make only dots on the main line

[image]

Comment: Do you want dots (circles or something) *on* the blue line?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about using a suitable [marker](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html)?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

losses = [12,13,15,10,9,8]
dots = [1,0,0,1,0,0]

# value from losses whenever corresponding dots value is 1:
d = [v if d else None for d, v in zip(dots, losses)]

plt.plot(losses, c='b')
plt.plot(d, c='b', marker='|', markersize=40)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram doesn't match your description, but here's how to do what you described.  You do the points as a scatter plot.  You can use numpy's fancy indexing to pick the points from the x and y axes where "dots" is True.  Note that it has to be True/False, so I used `==1` to convert your numbers to booleans.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

losses = np.array([12,13,15,10,9,8])
dots = np.array([1,0,0,1,0,0])==1
x = np.arange(6)*50000

xscat = x[dots]
yscat = losses[dots]

plt.plot(x, losses, c = 'b')
plt.scatter(xscat, yscat, c='r');
plt.show()
```

[image]